# Viewing E-R relationships on a Database in IntelliJ using the UML Plugin

Tags: database, intellij-idea, uml, erd

The diagram feature in IntelliJ IDEA  (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+U) for Database tables is very nice, it brings the tables into view, but not the relationships between the tables. Does the UML Plugin support viewing the entity relationships?  It wasn't clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The UML Plugin is working as designed. It's just that none of the tables in the project that I was checking had any foreign keys defined...